# Kafka behavior during partition re-balancing

Tags: apache-kafka

Given the following scenario: There is a Kafka (2.1.1) topic with 2 partitions and one consumer. A producer sends a message with keyX to Kafka which ends up on partition 2. The consumer starts processing this message. At the same time a new consumer is starting up and Kafka re-balances the topic. Consumer 1 is now responsible only for partition 1, consumer 2 is responsible for partition 2. The producer sends a message again with the same keyX, this time it will be consumer 2 which processes the message.

Consumer 2 might be processing the message, while consumer 1 has not finished yet.

My question is whether this is a realistic scenario or not, since it might be a problem for me if different consumers would process a message with the same key at the same time.

Any thought on this is welcome, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's a realistic scenario. Nevertheless, during a rebalance consumer 1 will closed all of its existing connections. In your case, consumer 1 will closed connections to partition 1 and 2 so it may not have committed its offset before message processing. It may depend if you have configured your consumer with the property `enable.auto.commit` to true. With this property set to true, consumer will periodically commit its current offset. The period is defined with `auto.commit.interval.ms`.

You can also be nofity when a rebalance occurs thanks to consumer listener `[ConsumerRebalanceListener][1]`. It enables to know when a partition is revoked or reassigned.